# How to convert set into list of float type?

Tags: python, list, set, python-3.6

I have a `mark_list` of float type , in which I am trying to sort in ascending order.

```
mark_list
Out[100]: [39, 37.21, 38, 37.21, 37.2]

sorted(mark_list)
Out[101]: [37.2, 37.21, 37.21, 38, 39]

set(sorted(mark_list))
Out[102]: {37.2, 37.21, 38, 39}

list(set(sorted(mark_list)))
Out[103]: [37.21, 37.2, 38, 39]
```

I expected a output `[37.2, 37.21, 38, 39]`

Why 37.21  is ahead of 37.2 ? What am I missing?

Comment: `set` is not ordered

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sets are not ordered. If you wish to have a sorted list, first get the set, then convert to list, finally sort.

Comment: You can skip the `list` conversion, `sorted` takes any *iterable* and returns a `list`…

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you don't want to use `set` in this case.
Here its important to consider that:

### A `set`

> is an unordered collection with no duplicate elements. Basic uses
>   include membership testing and eliminating duplicate entries.

you can read more at [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set)